# Unhandled JS Exception: Unexpected identifier '_Object$defineProperty'. Import expects exactly one argument

Tags: javascript, react-native

### Description:

I'm getting a very vague error when I run my project (that was previously working), I'm guessing at this point that it has nothing to do with my project.

After spending most of the day yesterday trying to figure it out, I realized that react-native had updated itself.

### What I've tried:

After cleaning the project with the various tools, I got rid of another error which was causing the project to fail during the build process (`react-native run-ios`).

```
yarn upgrade
yarn cache clean
react-native upgrade
rm -rf ios/build/; kill $(lsof -t -i:8081); react-native run-ios
```

However, I'm still getting the same issues

There are also issues mentioned on the babel github that seem to talk about a similar issue:

https://github.com/babel/babel-loader/issues/195

### Question

Why am I getting a vague error saying I have an unhandled js exception?

### Files that are relative to the issue:

**.babelrc**

```
{
  "presets": ["react-native"],
  "plugins": ["transform-decorators-legacy",
    "transform-async-generator-functions",
    "transform-object-rest-spread",
    "transform-class-properties",
    "transform-regenerator"]
}
```

**`react-native info`**

```
Environment:
  OS: macOS High Sierra 10.13.5
  Node: 9.5.0
  Yarn: 1.6.0
  npm: 5.6.0
  Watchman: 4.9.0
  Xcode: Xcode 9.4.1 Build version 9F2000
  Android Studio: 3.1 AI-173.4670197

Packages: (wanted => installed)
  react: ^16.3.0-alpha.1 => 16.4.1
  react-native: 0.54.4 => 0.54.4
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "FluxRN",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "mobx": "^5.0.2",
    "mobx-react": "^5.2.3",
    "moment": "^2.22.0",
    "native-base": "^2.5.2",
    "react": "^16.3.0-alpha.1",
    "react-native": "0.54.4",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^4.6.0",
    "react-navigation": "^1.5.9"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-jest": "22.4.3",
    "babel-plugin-transform-async-generator-functions": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-plugin-transform-class-properties": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-plugin-transform-decorators": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy": "^1.3.5",
    "babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-regenerator": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "^6.23.0",
    "babel-preset-react-native": "4.0.0",
    "jest": "22.4.3",
    "react-test-renderer": "^16.3.0-alpha.1"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this problem, I had to upgrade my react and react-native dependencies to the latest version, which solved the problem.

```
{
  "name": "FluxRN",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "moment": "^2.22.0",
    "native-base": "^2.5.2",
    "react": "^16.3.1",
    "react-native": "0.55.4",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^4.6.0",
    "react-navigation": "^1.5.9"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-jest": "23.0.1",
    "babel-preset-react-native": "4.0.0",
    "jest": "23.1.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "^16.3.1"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```